# Bootstrap 5 - make sidebar size line up with navbar brand

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

This page uses two navbar items, one for the top bar, and a separate one for the sidebar. How can I make it so the width of the sidebar is consistent with the end of the logo in the top right?

Using variations of col-xxl-1 etc. results in sizes that are too small or too large at various screensizes.

Thank you.

EDIT:
There are several possible approaches, in the end I ignored matching the size. Using col sizes never would have worked

- Pass exact width to css class for sidebar
- set sidebar to col-auto size, and place the logo inside the sidebar but make it invisble
- have the sidebar go to the top, and the top navbar comes after. Effectively the page becomes two columns, one for sidebar one for nav+content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using one of the column sizes have you tried using a style attribute or css class to pass in the exact width?